# How can i check class in css with checbox in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, class, laravel

So i want to change css class in HTML with checkbox. I know how boolean works, but how can i change text. For example, if checkbox is checked i want to inject "pull-right" class, and if it's not, then "pull-left" is defaulf.

I tried few things, but it wont work. Anyone knows how to create this?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I would love to, but it's a mess, and even i don't understand what i did. Can you create some simple demo?

Comment: why not use javascript or jQuery should be supper easy to do. In jQuery you can use click method and .addClass when clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it like this:

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="pull-left">Some Content </div>

<input type="checkbox" id="mybox"/>
```

Sample Javascript

```
$("#mybox").on("change", function(){
    $('#container').toggleClass("pull-left").toggleClass("pull-right");

})
```

[Working sample on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EMWU/wb45v/13/)

Comment: This is similar to what i need, but it's still blurry to me. I dont need to change classes "live" i need to save it in database and pull out string?

Comment: I don't understand really what you mean here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by doing this:

Jquery

```
    $(function(){

        $("input[name=toggle-checkbox]").on("change", function(){

            $(".test").toggleClass("pull-left").toggleClass("pull-right");

        });

    });
```

Then in your html add this:

```
    <input name="toggle-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    <div class="test pull-left"></div>
```

And a bit of css to see the effect:

```
    .test{
        display:block;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
    .pull-left{
        background-color:red;
    }

    .pull-right{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
```

I hope this helps!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jquery tag to your question. so let me give you **pure javascript** solution:

**fiddle**: **http://jsfiddle.net/Nz8Tq/**

**html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="change" id="change"/>change class    
<div class="pull-left" id="container"></div>
```

**javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("change").onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
        document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("class","pull-right"); 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("class","pull-left"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS only  <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/CRAXg/1/)**</kbd>

The `:checked` pseudo-class in CSS selects elements when they are in the selected state. It is only associated with input `<input>` elements of type radio and checkbox . The `:checked` pseudo-class selector matches radio and checkbox input types when checked or toggled to an on state. If they are not selected or checked, there is no match.

```
Browser Support
Chrome  Safari  Firefox Opera     IE    Android    iOS
Any     3.1+    Any     9+        9+    any        any
```

[source](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] ~ div { /* I used general sibling selector u can use other css selectors according to ur requirement like adjacent sibling, child selector etc */
    color: #ccc;
    font-style: italic;
    float: left
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div {
    color: #f00;
    font-style: normal;
    float: right
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" name="chkbx">
    <br>
<div for="chkbx">The power of css</div>
```